# PostgreSQL Views are disappearing

Tags: database, postgresql

We created several views postgresql 12 (not materialized views) which include nested queries and multiple joins.
we are facing a strange behavior, are noticing that some views are disappearing from the view list and others are remaining. is this related to Database configuration.

Are we missing some configuration?

Comment: this should be asked at DBA

Comment: Something is DROPing them. This is impossible to answer remotely.

Comment: any ideas from where to start digging ?,

Comment: Are they being created as `TEMPORARY` views?

Comment: Check the log files, if you log the ddl

Comment: no not temporary views

Comment: a drop/recreate of the underlying table maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess, but the one way that views can disappear is if you `DROP` them. You'd probably remember if you dropped them directly, but you can drop them indirectly with

```
DROP TABLE some_table CASCADE;
```

If you do that, all views and materialized views that depend on that table are dropped as well.

Answer (score 0):

We didn't drop the tables directly, however since we are using ESRI ArcGIS Desktop to manage our GIS data which is hosted on a PostgreSQL database. we identified the cause of the issue after the admin replaced all the tables in the schema. and ArcGIS Desktop dropped the tables and deleting the views  without informing the admin.